# Unable to hide app on appstore

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I want to hide my app temporarily on appstore. For this I followed guidelines from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3468583/437146) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4612652/437146). Moreover, I have set the Availability Date to some future date and app status has been changed to `Developer Removed From Sale`. But I don't know why my app is still searchable on app store. Does it take time to be removed completely from app store? If yes, then how much long?

Comment: Your question is not within the scope of Stack Overflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/help for what kinds of questions should be asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a while for changes to propagate. Give it at least 24 hours. I recently experienced a delay when releasing a new app. It took at least 24 hours before it could be found on an iOS device, although some were able to find it through iTunes on the desktop much sooner.

I'm sure the App Store lives on hundreds of servers throughout the world, which often means changes are only propagated instantly if absolutely necessary because of the extra work and hardware it would require.

Comment: Thank you for ur reply. I was worried if steps have been followed correctly or not :)